# Como melhorar o async nesse caso

Tags: javascript, promises, bluetooth

Estou usando a API Bluetooth padrão do chromium, ela faz a conexão com o bluetooth pegando seus serviços e características para então finalmente poder usar os métodos que as características possuem e tudo assíncrono, ok até aí.

Acontece 1 problema que a impressora só imprime uma certa quantidade de caracteres por causa da limitação em bytes então resolvi fazer um for para imprimir letra por letra (uma gambiarra que vem a calhar mt bem), assim ele imprime quantas eu quiser. O outro problema é: o for só funciona se eu colocar o alert(testo[i]) funcionando como uma pausa para esperar a promise se resolver.

**Depois de entenderem o que eu fiz, finalmente a pergunta: Como eu uso a promise corretamente para ela imprimir a próxima letra só quando a outra promise tiver resolved ou rejected sem o uso do alert?**

*Eu sei que texto é com x, não repare o nome da variável*

Com a resposta do Gabriel o código se tornou:

```js
const imprimir = (letra) => printCharacteristic.writeValue(letra).catch((e) => console.log(e.message));

testo.split('').forEach(
  async (letra) => {
    //alert("a")
    encoded = encoder.encode(letra);
    console.log(letra);
    await imprimir(encoded)
  }
);
```

[image: Diferença com alert e sem alert]

Esqueci de postar a solução, eu a encontrei um dia depois de postar aqui...

[Veja o arquivo todo no meu git](https://github.com/rennerw/escposbluetooth/blob/master/html/printer.html#L157)

O que eu fiz foi dividir a string em pedaços de até 18 caracteres (pois havia um limite de bytes), após isso um for async para cada item do array da variavel letras. Cada item devia esperar 500 ms para enviar o comando de print pra impressora, assim, fazendo tudo funcionar direitinho :D . Fazendo alguns testes, observei que o modelo da minha impressora printava tmb sem qqer problemas em 200ms.

Agradeço à todos que tentaram ajudar. Obrigado

Comment: Como a printCharacteristic.writeValue(letra) já é uma promise, vc não precisa criar uma nova como está fazendo. 

Você consegue fazer assim:

const imprimir = (letra) => printCharacteristic.writeValue(letra)

E a iteração, você pode fazer assim:

texto.forEach(async (letra) => {
  encoded = encoder.encode(testo[i]);
  await imprimir(encoded)
})

Comment: Perfeito, vc entendeu certinho o que eu quis dizer. O seu código funciona com uma simples alteração pra texto.split('').forEach(...). Esse são os console log que fiz:
p:143 t
p:143 e
p:143 s
p:143 t
3 GATT operation already in progress. -> 4 letras digitadas, 3 letras caíram no catch() da promise
p:164 Imprimiu pt 2 -> apenas UMA letra foi impressa aqui
Com o alert("a") o código ainda funciona "perfeito" imprimindo tds letras
async (letra) => {
              alert("a")
              encoded = encoder.encode(letra);
              await imprimir(encoded)
          });

Comment: Se funcionou, coloca como resposta galera!

Comment: Não funcionou ainda, Samuel :(

Comment: Poderia usar `Promise.all` para esperar todos resultados, creio que será bem mais simples que criar uma cadeia.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, o problema de se usar `Promise.all` nesse caso é que esse método não executa as promessas em sequência, mas sim em paralelo. E isso pode não ser o que o AP quer. [Veja um exemplo disso aqui.](https://i.imgur.com/FPAC43L.png)

Comment: @LuizFelipe tem toda razão, mas no caso se você "enumerar" dentro do loop você tem como criar um indice para saber a ordem desejada e reordenar no final, claro que isso vai bem mais do que usar um loop, mas ainda sim é parte de criar uma lógica necessária :)

Comment: Completamente válido! :) Inclusive, nunca tinha pensado nisso e gostei da ideia. :v

Answer (score 1):

O método [`forEach` do array](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) não é ideal para se lidar com promessas. Para lidar com listas de promessas, sugiro que você utilize o [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) com [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) ou usar um laço de repetição `for` dentro de uma função assíncrona.

Como no seu caso a ordem da execução das promessas é importante, a segunda alternativa (laço `for`) é um pouco mais vantajosa. Então, você pode fazer algo assim:

```
const print = (letter) => printCharacteristic
  .writeValue(letter)
  .catch((e) => console.log(e.message));

(async () => {
  const letters = text.split('');

  // Iteramos sobre cada letra:
  for (const letter of letters) {
    await print(letter);
    // A próxima iteração só acontecerá após a resolução dessa promisse.
  }
})();
```

Comment: Exatamente, dando uma pesquisada eu vi que o forEach nao lida com promessas, encontrei um artigo muito bom no Medium que salvou minha vida haha. https://medium.com/@mathiasghenoazzolini/javascript-loops-com-async-await-8b07caf38017